# Unable to create PeerAdminCard

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/installing/development-tools.html) simple tutorial to set up my dev environment . Everything goes fine until I trigger ./createPeerAdminCard.sh which gives error as below

> Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
>   Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
>   FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv11'
>   FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
>
> Using composer-cli at v0.17.4
>
> Successfully created business network card file to    Output file:
>   /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card
>
> Command succeeded
>
> Error: No connection type provided, probably because the connection
>   profile has no 'x-type' property defined. Command failed

I am using composer version v0.17.4 and fabric at 1.1.0 - alpha on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get this error because your card store still has a PeerAdmin card in it that was created using Composer 0.16 or earlier. The cards are not compatible so when the cli tries to delete the card it cannot. The quickest solution is to remove the file system card store completely. Currently the file system card store will always be at `${HOME}/.composer` so to delete it you would do

`rm -fr ${HOME}/.composer`

Comment: @Karimai ,You have to run the ./createPeerAdminCard.sh after running the said command.